# Is it possible to write custom decorators in D? Similar to python,

Tags: d

In python you have a function decorators.  Is it possible to do something similar in D?
something like:

```
@memoize("expensiveCalc")
int expensiveCalc(string foo){
    ///bar
}
```

Comment: http://dlang.org/attribute.html

Comment: most of the time there is a second version and a template involved

Comment: @ratchetfreak It seems that this is only useful at compilation.  Does this mean I wouldn't be able to achieve something such as a memoize UDA. (Basically it would hash my arguments and store the function result for caching purposes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. However, in D it is called an ["user defined attribute" (UDA)](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#uda). It has been introduced in D relatively recently, and since then people use it more and more to annotate their functions.

Comment: User Defined Attributes are quite different from python decorators, which can wrap or even completely replace the body of the function.